# Order by Month and Year Columns by using concat() and cast()

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently concatenating columns monthly_volunteer_ccyy and monthly_volunteer_month by year which converts result to character string presumably. And then cating it to int to get the result set ordered by ccyymm.

Somehow it throws error near `INT)`. What could I do here to get it working?
Also bonus points for pointing out the clean way for this.

```
SELECT *
FROM monthly_honorarium_processing
ORDER BY cast(CONCAT (
        monthly_volunteer_ccyy
        ,monthly_volunteer_month
        ) AS INT)
```

Comment: `INT` is not a valid type for `CAST()` in MySQL:  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast, as you need `SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick change:

```
SELECT *
FROM monthly_honorarium_processing
ORDER BY cast(CONCAT (
        monthly_volunteer_ccyy
        ,monthly_volunteer_month
        ) AS DECIMAL)
```

This does not handle properly monthly_volunteer_month < 10

Why not just doing:

```
SELECT *
FROM monthly_honorarium_processing
ORDER BY
        monthly_volunteer_ccyy
        ,monthly_volunteer_month
```